# From Hackintosh to Macintosh

Tags: macos, mac-pro, migration, hackintosh

Ok. So I recently got a Mac Pro (older version) from a very generous person.
It rocks.
All this time, I've had to use a crappy computer that I've run macOS on, that wasn't meant to run macOS.

It was an unnatural and sinful act.

Anyway, ripped the hard drive out and stuck it into my real Mac.

Deleted the Clover boot loader, which acted like an immunosuppressant to keep macOS from rejecting the computer, but Wi-Fi still won't work, and I don't know what to do to rectify this.

Can you please help? Is there any other Hackintosh related thing I should remove?

Also used MultiBeast.

Comment: You'd probably do best to put a fresh OS on it, then migrate what you can from the old drive.

Comment: You took a drive with a bodged together version of macOS on it into a genuine Mac and you want to "unbodge" it to make it work?  Wipe clean and start fresh.

Comment: No, it's vanilla mac either way. Not some weird pirated version with a foreign kernel. P.s I want my documents.

Comment: Didn't say "pirated" or "foreign".  I said [bodged](https://www.bing.com/search?q=definition+of+bodged).  Copy your docs to the cloud or a USB stick - you do make backups, right?

Comment: The Mac may be vanilla, but your boot drive is 57 flavours, with sprinkles. I'd be surprised if you could get a Mac to boot with Clover or MultiBeast on there getting in the way & trying to do what the Mac is perfectly capable of doing itself.

Comment: Like I said, I removed clover

Comment: Put the drive back in the old system, then create a backup of all your work - of course this will be a second copy ..... And then put the backed up files on the mac using its own drive and Apple accepted system.

Answer (score 8):

Like all the comments say, "install macOS fresh."

What you are doing is taking a VW based dune buggy and trying to turn it back into a VW Bug. It will be both quicker and easier to to boot into recovery mode. Install a fresh copy of macOS and then using the Migration Assistant, migrate your files, preferences and apps from the Hackintosh drive to the drive that came with the Mac.

That is **exactly** what the Migration Assistant is designed for: getting *everything you need* from one Mac to another quickly and easily